# Place HTML in a Rails Helper

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, helper

So i have an input for a simple_form like this:

```
<%= f.input :preferred_locale, collection: languages_available, label: "Choose Language", selected: current_user.preferred_locale, include_blank: false %>
```

So this creates a dropdown with languages available in the project. Languages available is an array like this, placed in a rails helper (extension .rb, only ruby, file):

```
def languages_available
    [
      ["English", 'en'],
      ["Spanish", 'es'],
    ]
end
```

The thing is want to display an icon right next to the language displaying the country flag. Thing is, in helpers you cant write html. No problem, i know the existence of html_safe, so in the collection i did something like:

```
<%= f.input :preferred_locale, collection: languages_available.map { |e| e.map(&:html_safe) }, label: "Choose Language", selected: current_user.preferred_locale,include_blank: false %>
```

So this marks as html_Safe every substring. With this i never see anything, and i am trying something as simple as putting in the array

```
def languages_available
    [
      ["<b>English</b>", 'en'],
      ["Spanish", 'es'],
    ]
end
```

the thing is something is working since i only see "English" and not "< b> English < /b>" as plaint text,  but im not seeing the word in bold font so i dont know whats wrong.

edit: thank you for the answers, seems like in collection, which generates a select tag, is not possible to  use html since it only supports text, i'll have to find another way of accomplishing this.

Comment: The only permitted content inside an `option` tag is text: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Comment: You can create HTML elements in your helper, but it's not the problem. HTML does not allow customization of a `select` element. You have to create your own 'fake' `select`. There's some plugins to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can do it in Html, options are not customizable, but maybe u can use a list, and with css and/or js customize to do a dropdown, I know that exist a lot of libraries to do it.

Here you have an example: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_button

Another thing maybe is use emojis with the flags, I never tried but maybe you can put it plain text and with some library automatically convert it to an emoji.